# Tidyverse and dplyr- error package or namespace

Tags: r, tidyverse

I can't seem to get the filter function to work along with the loading of tidyverse. I have compared code and know that it is correct however I get error messages every time. I have checked multiple online resources and none seem to help. I also have updated all of my packages and restarted them. Any help is appreciated!

This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = mpg) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = Hwy))

filter(mpg, cyl == 8)
filter(diamonds, carat > 3)
```

Errors:

```
library(tidyverse)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(I, 
c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.3 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.6.3 

filter(mpg, cyl == 8)

Error in filter(mpg, cyl == 8) : object 'cyl' not found
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
    2: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
    3: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
    4: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
    5: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
    6: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion

    filter(diamonds, carat > 3)

    Error in filter(diamonds, carat > 3) : object 'carat' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `tidyverse` is not being loaded into your R session, and so when you call `filter`, it is from the `stats` package rather than dplyr. This is why it's good practice to use namespaces in R, like `dplyr::filter`, so you know exactly which function you are calling.

To fix the error loading tidyverse,  update the  `rlang` library:

```
update.packages()
```

And then try

```
dplyr::filter(mtcars, cyl == 8)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I unloaded and updated but for the second line of code I'm haveing some issues.

Comment: dplyr::filter(mpg, cyl == 8)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.3 is required

Comment: try unloadNamespace("rlang") and then updating it

Comment: I'm sorry but it is still producing the same error. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: You may need to restart R. Because many of these packages have compiled shared objects (`.dll`, `.so`, or `.lib`, depending on the OS), those are not always easy to "unload". As such, when you see problems like this, a common remedy is to restart R. If it persists, make sure you do not have an `.Rdata` file being loaded (which is in my experience often a bad idea anyway, I have that feature disabled).

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong. I have restarted my program, updated using the update button in packages and following what you recommended. I finally am getting a different error message for the filter code: Error in as.ts(x): object 'mpg' not found. However, Tidyverse still will not load correctly

Comment: Ah, that's because the syntax for dplyr::filter is dplyr::filter(data, condition) - mpg isn't the data, mtcars is. So using dplyr::filter(mtcars, cyl == 8) should return the rows in mtcars where cyl is equal to 8